# No se muestra la notificación en Windows con un NotifyIcon de C#

Tags: c#

Estoy tratando de probar el uso de un NotifyIcon en C#, con la documentación y videos, pero al disparar un evento que tiene que mostrarme una notificación, la misma no se muestra. Hice el paso a paso del procedimiento que realiza el programa hasta llegar a las notificaciones, y no me da error, pero no me muestra nada.

¿Se debe a algo en particular que hago mal? Este es el método que llamo, para que se muestre la noti:

```
private void Notificacion()
{
   Notificacion.Text = "xxxxx";
   Notificacion.BalloonTipTitle = "xxxx";
   Notificacion.BalloonTipText = "Texto a mostrar";
   Notificacion.BalloonTipIcon = ToolTipIcon.Info;
   Notificacion.Visible = true;
   Notificacion.ShowBalloonTip(6000);
}
```

Donde "Notificacion" sería el nombre del control NotifyIcon.

Vi varios videos donde hacen lo mismo, pero no cambia absolutamente nada y les funciona bien, pero a mi no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que el `notifyIcon` funcione correctamente debes seleccionarle un icono.

Para ello ve a a las propiedades del control y en la propiedad icon pulsa el botoncito de los 3 puntos seleccionas el icono y listo, este icono no tiene nada que ver con el de la propiedad `BallonTipIcon`

Comment: Por dioooo!!!!! La pavada que era. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda!! Genio/a.